# How can I represent these symbols?

Tags: symbols

Can someone tell me how to write these symbols in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: `$a_{-k}=a_{k}^{*}$` Any basic introduction to LaTeX should explain math mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
$a_{-k}=a^{*}_k$,
```

or, but more dubiously,

```
$a_{-k}=a^{*}_{k{\mbox{\textquoteright}}}$
```

Comment: That seems clearly a comma